# How to know which syntax highlighting is being used in vim?

Tags: vi

Newbie here. I opened a file without any extension with VIM, and its syntax is highlighted. I want to know **which command** will show me that which syntax highlighting is being used? i.e., is this a C++ highlighting or C highlighting....?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about UNIX/Linux

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VIM tries to automatically detect file type by default.  To see which file type is currently detected type (in command mode):

```
:set filetype?
```

to set it to any particular type:

```
:set filetype=<filetype>
```